# How to write a calculation query in MySQL with 2 tables?

Tags: mysql

I've 2 tbls as follow.

request tbl

```
id | request | created
1  | asdf    | 2013-07-04 14:39:03
2  | qwer    | 2013-07-10 12:06:37
```

history tbl

```
id | request_id | status       | date
1  |     1      | Pending      | 2013-07-04 14:39:03
2  |     1      | Reviewing    | 2013-07-05 01:10:14
3  |     1      | Implementing | 2013-07-06 11:25:54
4  |     1      | Completed    | 2013-07-07 12:36:32
5  |     2      | Pending      | 2013-07-10 15:05:56
6  |     2      | Reviewing    | 2013-07-11 03:08:04
7  |     2      | Implementing | 2013-07-13 11:45:48
8  |     2      | Completed    | 2013-07-17 14:28:15
```

I want to display above 2 tbls as follow

```
Request | Reviewing Time | Implementing Time 
asdf    |      0         |      0            
qwer    |      1         |      2
```

The theories with examples of request_id = 1 are

> reviewing to implementing = (2013-08-06) - (2013-08-05) = 1 day
>
> pending to reviewing = (2013-08-05) - (2013-08-04) = 1 day
>
> **Reviewing Time** = (reviewing to implementing) - (pending to reviewing)
>   = 0 day
>
> reviewing to implementing = (2013-08-06) - (2013-08-05) = 1 day
>
> implementing to completed = (2013-08-07) - (2013-08-06) = 1 day
>
> **Implementing Time** = (implementing to compeleted) - (reviewing to
>   implementing) = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a long-hand way of solving it...

```
 CREATE TABLE my_table 
 (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,request_id INT NOT NULL
 ,status       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
 ,date DATETIME NOT NULL
 ,UNIQUE(request_id,status)
 );

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 (1  ,1      ,'Pending','2013-07-04 14:39:03'),
 (2  ,     1      ,'Reviewing','2013-07-05 01:10:14'),
 (3  ,     1      ,'Implementing','2013-07-06 11:25:54'),
 (4  ,     1     ,'Completed','2013-07-07 12:36:32'),
 (5  ,     2     ,'Pending','2013-07-10 15:05:56'),
 (6  ,     2     ,'Reviewing','2013-07-11 03:08:04'),
 (7  ,     2     ,'Implementing','2013-07-13 11:45:48'),
 (8  ,     2     ,'Completed','2013-07-17 14:28:15');

 SELECT request_id
      , DATEDIFF(implementing,reviewing) - DATEDIFF(reviewing,pending) rT
      , DATEDIFF(completed,implementing) - DATEDIFF(implementing,reviewing) iT
 FROM (
 SELECT x.request_id
      , MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'pending' THEN date END) pending 
      , MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'reviewing' THEN date END) reviewing
      , MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'implementing' THEN date END) implementing
      , MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'completed' THEN date END) completed
   FROM my_table x
  GROUP 
     BY request_id
     ) a;

 +------------+------+------+
 | request_id | rT   | iT   |
 +------------+------+------+
 |          1 |    0 |    0 |
 |          2 |    1 |    2 |
 +------------+------+------+
```

sqlfiddle of same: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc6db/1

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understood right what you need, but here is example of what i readed out from your question. In example i use nested queries to get calculations for every request. DATEDIFF gives difference of 2 dates in days. I use ABS because i assume you do not want negative numbers and i was not sure if those dates allways gives positive number. Those in example gives it without abs allso.

```
SELECT calc.request, ABS(calc.`reviewing to implementing`-calc.`pending to reviewing`) AS 'Reviewing Time', ABS(calc.`implementing to completed`-calc.`reviewing to implementing`) AS 'Implementing Time'
    FROM (
        SELECT t1.request,
        (
            SELECT ABS(DATEDIFF((SELECT `date` FROM history_tbl WHERE request_id = t1.id AND `status` = 'Reviewing'), (SELECT `date` FROM history_tbl WHERE request_id = t1.id AND `status` = 'Implementing')))
        ) AS 'reviewing to implementing',
        (
            SELECT ABS(DATEDIFF((SELECT `date` FROM history_tbl WHERE request_id = t1.id AND `status` = 'Pending'), (SELECT `date` FROM history_tbl WHERE request_id = t1.id AND `status` = 'Reviewing')))
        ) AS 'pending to reviewing',
        (
            SELECT ABS(DATEDIFF((SELECT `date` FROM history_tbl WHERE request_id = t1.id AND `status` = 'Implementing'), (SELECT `date` FROM history_tbl WHERE request_id = t1.id AND `status` = 'Completed')))
        ) AS 'implementing to completed'
        FROM request_tbl as t1
    ) AS calc
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da4855/1/0)